403 Forbidden Error When Calling API in POSTMAN
I'm trying to learn web scraping and saw a video that said I can, "look for the hidden API" instead of using selenium to get data from dynamically loaded html. I found the GET request that has data that I want, copied its uCURL, put it in the POSTMAN request, and sent it, but what I get back is just HTML, and its the same HTML when I try scraping the page using Beautiful Soup, which is weird because the whole reason I went this route was to get around the initial HTML that's loaded onto the page.
My headers have user-agent, csrf token, referer, accept set to json, and many others, but I'm a bit stuck here. The website I'm trying to scrape is weis, so it also may be I'm missing authorization which is why I'm getting 403 forbidden?
Sorry if I'm missing any details that would help or if the explanation is confusin. I'm pretty new to this so any help would be great. Thanks.

Postman is not SPELLED IN ALL CAPS ARGH WHY IS EVERYONE SHOUTING

Web-services often implement various means of detecting browser-based web-scrapers (like Postman, Selenium/Puppeteer, etc) and blocking them with 403 - consider yourself lucky that you're getting a straightforward result. Other web-services go into honeypot mode and will serve up bogus data in order to waste your time (kinda like a trap-street).

Ahh I see, thanks for the insight. Is there a work around here? I thought web scraping would've been okay with this site because the robot.txt thing didn't mention that this page wasn't allowed. My goal here is to just get the current price of grocery store items

Why bother with a robots.txt file when 99% of bots out there (especially scapers) are going to ignore it?

Because I'm having trouble scraping the site and I thought maybe it was because it wasn't allowed. Either way, is trying to get data from the API a lost cause? Or would something like Selenium be better here
